# Facing issue while using SparkUDF with multiple arguments

Tags: apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am trying to encript the data using SHA-256 by passing as an argument in Spark UDF but getting below error. Please find the program snippet and error details below.

Code Snippet:

```
package com.sample
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import java.security.MessageDigest
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

object Customer {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Customer-data").setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.executor.memory", "1g");

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(sc.getConf).getOrCreate()
    //val hash_algm=sc.getConf.get("halgm")
    val hash_algm="SHA-256"

    val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("file:///home/tcs/Documents/KiranDocs/Data_files/sample_data")
    spark.udf.register("encriptedVal1", encriptedVal)
    //calling encription UDF function
    //val resDF1 = df.withColumn(("ssn_number"), encriptedVal(df("customer_id"))).show()
    val resDF2 = df.withColumn(("ssn_number"), encriptedVal(array("customer_id", hash_algm))).show()


    println("data set"+resDF2)   


    sc.stop()

  }
   def encriptedVal = udf((s: String,s1:String) => {
    val digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(s1)
    val hash = digest.digest(s.getBytes("UTF-8"))
    DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(hash)
  })

}
```

Error details are below:

> Exception in thread "main" 2019-01-21 19:42:48 INFO  SparkContext:54 -
>   Invoking stop() from shutdown hook java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.sample.Customer$$anonfun$encriptedVal$1 cannot be cast to
>   scala.Function1   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.(ScalaUDF.scala:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction.apply(UserDefinedFunction.scala:85)
>     at com.sample.Customer$.main(Customer.scala:26)     at
>   com.sample.Customer.main(Customer.scala)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is how you call the defined UDF. You should use it like the following:

```
val resDF1 = df.withColumn(("ssn_number"), encriptedVal(df.col("customer_id"), lit(hash_algm)))
```

because it accepts two `Column`s object (both `Column`s must be `String` type as defined in your UDF).